# Change child color on hover over parent background image

Tags: html, css, sass, anchor

I created an anchor link with a background image. I also have a `span` tag that holds some text as well. My intended effect is to have the color of the span tag change when a user hovers over the entire image and not just the span tag (which is positioned in the middle of the background image).

Here's my HTML:

```
<a class="photos" href="link/to/folder">
  <span>Event Photos</span>
</a>
```

And here is my SCSS:

```
.photos {display: block;
background: url('imgs/photos-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
background-size:cover;
height: auto; 
padding-top: 11%; 
padding-bottom: 14%;
@include transition(all .3s ease-in-out);
 span {width: 20%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: $drkgrey;
 text-align: center; 
 @include sansproxlgt(em(28)); 
 color: $white; 
 padding:1% 1%; 
 display: block;
   &:hover{color: $blue;}
 }
}
```

I feel that I am close, but I am not sure where I am getting hung up.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.photos:hover span {color: #color;}
```

Comment: He doesn't want the hover to trigger on the text but on the background image. This doesnt address the question.

Comment: I disagree. He or she says very specifically: "My intended effect is to have the color of the span tag change when a user hovers over the entire image"

Comment: @Jonline And it will?  The trigger is the anchor tag (`a.photos:hover`), the span is what's having its color modified.

Comment: Yep. Missed the inclusion of the span selector. My bad—one espresso too many. :#|

Comment: This worked. Just need to figure out how to add in the hover transitions.

Comment: If you'll create a new issue with your updated code, I'll help you out. It's hard to tell what you're working with now.

Answer (score 0):

In SASS:

```
&hover: {
     span { color:$blue;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to know this was my final SCSS to get this to work.
Thanks to Jonline and Gray Spectrum for the insight!

```
a.photos {
 display: block;
 background: url('imgs/photos-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
 background-size:cover;
 height: auto; 
 padding: 14% 0;
  span {
   width: 20%; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   background: $drkgrey; 
   text-align: center; 
   @include sansproxlgt(em(28)); 
   color: $white; 
   padding:1% 1%; 
   display: block; 
   @include transition(all .3s ease-in-out);
     @media screen and (max-width: 36.5em ) {
      width: 30%;}
  }
  &:hover span {color: $blue;}
}
```